# Python 2.7 - Beautiful Soup Web Scraping find_all command not working

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am testing out the beautiful soup web scraping tools. The code below simply connects to a subreddit and attempts to print the link of all the images from the user posts on the first page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics"
r = requests.get(url)

if r.status_code != 200:
    print "failed to connect"
    exit()

sourcecode = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(sourcecode, "html.parser")

print soup

for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'title may-blank outbound srTagged'}):
    print "entered into for loop"

    if tag['href'].startswith('http'):
        print tag['href']
```

This code causes the correct `soup` object to be printed and I can see it all. However, the `soup.find_all('a', {'class':'title may-blank outbound srTagged'})` command returns an empty list. There is no error, only an empty list which means the for-loop at the end doesn't even get run.

I am wondering what is wrong here. I have copied and pasted the strings over and I can see the links I'm trying to print on the web source code **[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ritzq.png)**.

I am referring to the line:

```
<a class = "title may-blank outbound srTagged" ...
```

Which I copied and pasted over to my code to avoid spelling mistakes and still nothing happens... any ideas why the command returns an empty list?

I have changed the for loop to `for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'thumbnail may-blank outbound'}):` which is another class name and it behaves normally.

Is the website just full on blocking Beautiful Soup from accessing that portion of the source code?

Comment: Do you want the link referring to the reddit thread, or the one referring to the external location of the image?

Comment: I was going for the link to the external location of the image (i.dailymail.co.uk.... etc). The idea would have been to make a list of all the image links on a reddit page and then pass them through a separate function that would simply download all the images from the list of links that was supposed to be output from the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are experiencing [differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers), switch to a more lenient `html5lib`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sourcecode, "html5lib")
```

This needs `html5lib` to be installed.

Also, you can simplify the way you are locating the links:

- use [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and check for `title` and `outbound` classes only
- don't check for `href` values to start with `http` since `outbound` class implicitly defines it

Fixed version:

```
for tag in soup.select('a.title.outbound'):
    print(tag['href'])
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks - still learning the basics so any tips on efficiency help!

Answer (score 0):

`html.parser` is broken in Python2, and the BeautifulSoup [Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) mentioned it:

> If you can, I recommend you install and use `lxml` for speed. If
>   you’re using a version of Python 2 earlier than 2.7.3, or a version of
>   Python 3 earlier than 3.2.2, it’s essential that you install `lxml` or
>   `html5lib`**Python’s built-in HTML parser is just not very good in
>   older versions.**
>
> Note that if a document is invalid, different parsers will generate
>   different Beautiful Soup trees for it. See [Differences between
>   parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) for details.